# How to set another column with the value of the primary key on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

When creating a record I want to set a column called `original_id` to the value of its primary key (in this case `id`). In essence, the rows will become hierarchal and they will look like this:

```
| id | original_id |
| -- | ----------- |
|  1 |           1 |
|  2 |           1 |
|  3 |           1 |
| .. |           1 |
| 42 |          42 |
| 43 |          42 |
```

The model will look like this:

```
class AccountTransaction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :original,
             class_name: 'AccountTransaction',
             foreign_key: :original_id
end
```

It's easy to create the record then update like this:

```
record = AccountTransaction.create
record.update(original: record)
```

But I am looking for a more elegant solution, one that doesn't require two database transactions. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something with an `after_create` callback.

```
class AccountTransaction < ApplicationRecord

  after_create :upate_original_id

  def update_original_id
    update_attribute(original_id: id)
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks, for your input, but it's unfortunately not what I'm looking for. I want to do it in a single database transaction. Your code above is pretty much what I already have and I'm looking for a way to optimise it.

Comment: It is a single database transaction from the perspective of the developer.  He just codes `AccountTransaction.create` and the `original_id` is already populated.  The developer doesn't need to do anything in particular to ensure that happens.  That's the point of an ActiveRecord callback.